# How to make "Export-CSV" export quoting only texts?

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have an input file with the following data:

```
cod_uf;uf;nome_uf;pop_estimada
11;RO;Rondônia;1796460
12;AC;Acre;894470
13;AM;Amazonas;4207714
```

issuing the command `Import-Csv ".\in.csv" -Delimiter ";" | Export-Csv ".\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8` yields:

```
"cod_uf","uf","nome_uf","pop_estimada"
"11","RO","Rondônia","1796460"
"12","AC","Acre","894470"
"13","AM","Amazonas","4207714"
```

which is great, but it would be better if it quoted only non-numeric fields, like so:

```
"cod_uf","uf","nome_uf","pop_estimada"
11,"RO","Rondônia",1796460
12,"AC","Acre",894470
13,"AM","Amazonas",4207714
```

I couldn't find any mention or example to produce the desired output in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1).

To quote non-numeric field is useful when using python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library, where one could [set the reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.

Comment: Which PowerShell version? Did you try **`-QuoteFields uf, nome_uf`**?

Comment: Version 5.1. It wasn't implemented on this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$csv = @'
cod_uf;uf;nome_uf;pop_estimada
11;RO;Rondônia;1796460
12;AC;Acre;894470
13;AM;Amazonas;4207714
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

($csv | ConvertTo-Csv) -replace '"([0-9]+)"','$1' | Out-File .\out.csv
```

Comment: whats the `$1` for?

Comment: Works as expected. An example using a file: `(Import-Csv ".\input.csv" -Delimiter ";" | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"([0-9]+)"','$1' | Out-File .\out.csv` , I added `-NoTypeInformation` to remove the **#TYPE** information header

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `$1` is the group identifier, `$0` is the complete match, `$1` is what matches inside the `( )`. Try `([regex]'"([0-9]+)"').Match(($csv | ConvertTo-Csv)).Groups` from my example to help you understand.

Comment: Ohhhh, nice. Fancy indeed:)